# Authenticate user based on mobile device ID

Tags: android, ios, security, authentication, mobile

I have a hypothetical mobile game where players don't necessarily need to create accounts to play. Their data is keyed off of a device identifier like an advertising identifier (IDFA) or Apple's identifierForVendor or Android ID

For GDPR, I need to allow all users to download their data.

Is it safe to use the ID as an authentication secret to uniquely identify a user/device, or are these ID values predictable / published somewhere and easy to spoof?

Comment: I would highly advise against this. For one, if the device is passed on to someone else, you would be giving them access. And while the device ID is practically unique, it is possible for there to be a collision.

Comment: @JediBurrell good point. According to this Android [blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html), we could generate a UUID when the app is first installed. That and Apple's [identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor) would be unique to the user.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's perspective, this is a no-go.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/adsupport/asidentifiermanager

> The ASIdentifierManager class provides apps with access to an
>   identifier that can **be used only for serving advertisements**, as well
>   as a flag that indicates whether a user has limited ad tracking.

Should they find out you are using it for something else, you risk having your app removed and possibly being banned from the App store. YMMV.

Plus, if a user disables ad tracking in the OS, they will return a UUID of all zeroes, which will cause a lot of problems once more people do it since you are **guaranteed** an ID collision.

Comment: Thanks. I believe [identifierForVendor (linked)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor) would be preferred by Apple here.